# Alternative for Polling Record State

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sqlclr

We currently have a payment tracking system which uses MS SQL Server Enterprise. When a client requests a service, he would have to do the payment within 24 hours, otherwise we would send him an SMS Reminder. Our current implementation simply records the date and time of the purchase, and keep on polling constantly the records in order to find "expired" purchases.

This is generating so much load on the database that we have to implement some form of replication in order to offload these operations to another server.

I was thinking: is there a way to combine CLR triggers with some kind of a scheduler that would be triggered only once, that is, 24 hours after the purchase is created?

Please keep in mind that we have tens of thousands of transactions per hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you are thinking that SQLCLR will solve this problem. I don't think this needs to be handled in the DB at all.

Since the request time doesn't change, why not load all requests into a memory-based store that you can hit constantly. You would load the 24-hour-from-request time so that you only need to compare those times to Now. If the customer pays prior to the 24-hour period then you remove the entry from the cache. Else, the polling process will eventually find it, process it, and remove it from the cache.

OR, similarly, you can use a scheduler and load a future event to be the SMS message, based on the 24-hour-from-request time, upon each request. Similar to scheduling an action using "AT". Again, if someone pays prior to that time, just remove the scheduled task/event/reminder.

You would store just the 24-hour-after-time and the `RequestID`. If the time is reached, the service would refer back to the DB using that `RequestID` to get the current info.

You just need to make sure to de-list items from the cache / scheduler if payment is made prior to the 24-hour-after time.

And if the system crashes / restarts, you just load all entries that are a) unpaid, and b) have not yet reached their 24-hour-after time.

Comment: Using a memory cache depends on the size of the data of course
I'd have to consult the responsible teams about the maximum expected size of data

There is another problem though: these records represent monetary transactions, so any discrepancy between the cache and the database would mean huge losses to our company. This means that if for some reason the cache is flushed or the application is restarted, we would have to be extra careful about how we are going to populate this cache

Comment: @Sam You only need to store the 24-hour-after-time and the `RequestID` in the cache. Once the time hits, then you go back to the DB for the details. I don't see how there could be any discrepancy in any of the info, or how it would take up that much space.

Comment: That makes sense
I can synchronize the cache with the database, say, once every hour just to make sure that I'm not using stale data, and that would still be safe.
I'll give this question a couple of hours before marking your answer as the accepted one
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sam You can wait a day or 2 even. It's a major U.S. holiday so many folks might not even be checking today. I also just added some info to the end of my answer to clarify what we have been talking about in these comments.